# How to load my program in GAP system?

Tags: gap-system

After downloading the Windows version of the [GAP system](http://www.gap-system.org/), I want to ask if GAP can read the file in specified path in Windows? What is the command to load a GAP script in the Windows environment?

Answer (score 4):

The command is called `Read` (enter `?Read` in GAP to see the documentation). The trick on Windows is to replace `\` by `/`. For example one should call

```
gap> Read("C:/Users/myname/gap/program.g");
```

to read a file that Windows would call

```
C:\Users\myname\gap\program.g
```

Also, I'd recommend to avoid paths containing spaces.

P.S. If you prefer to ask questions about GAP in StackExchange framework, I'd recommend to try to ask them at the [Mathematics Q&A site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gap).

Comment: Another caveat under Windows is about creating a text file with an editor which automatically adds ".txt" extension to the file name, when Windows Explorer hides extensions for standard file types. Then `program.g` may be actually `program.g.txt`, but that wouldn't be obvious.